# What is the final word on page 47?

Tags: annoying-challenge

I'm trying to finish the "[Annoying Challenge](http://liam-galvin.co.uk/challenge/)".
For those who don't it, it's an internet riddle, you only get a few hints and you will have to come up with an answer, the riddles are very nerd-related. Some geek-knowledge is required.

Right now I'm stuck on question 6.
The first hint is a piece of text: "I'm making money out of you and watching you fail. Brilliant."
Followed by an advertisement about the book "[Nerd Do Well](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1846058112/ref=as_li_ss_til?tag=liagal-21&camp=2902&creative=19466&linkCode=as4&creativeASIN=1846058112&adid=0YHKTNA4KJB0JPZM0VPF&&ref-refURL=http://liam-galvin.co.uk/challenge/level/6)".
And a final clue: "Page 47, last word."

To get to question 6, here is a walktrough to get trough the first 5 puzzles:

> 0 = "your name" (take it literally)
>  1 = "poison" (found in your browser cookies, really clever...)
>  2 = "brownsea" (found by inserting the coords into google maps)
>  3 = "i <3 u" (No idea why, but it is)
>  4 = "alberteinstein" (decode base64, then md5)
>  5 = your actual ip-address (look it up)

Can anyone help me with the 6th question? What is the last word on page 47?

Comment: I'm confused. Is this an actual video game, browser based or otherwise, or is this some sort of scavenger hunt like game that uses hints from sites across the internet, like [DropQuest](https://www.dropbox.com/dropquest2012/)? Because if it's the latter, it's most likely off topic for this site

Comment: It's a browser-based riddle. I'm not familiar with DropQues. But it's still a considered a game right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right answer can be found by exploiting Amazon's "Look Inside" feature.

If you search for a term, you can see it in context on that page - so go to the index and find something on page 47, then search for it.

...or rather, that's what you would normally do. In this case, you can't, because the index doesn't contain anything on that page.

However, there are references to page *46*, and if you search for that, you can click the next page button to see page 47.

Exact answer given in spoiler:

> modicum

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the "look inside" feature.

Comment: Also, can you give me a hint about "What colour the ball is?" (question 8)

Comment: Never mind, the answer was right there in the page...